# System requirement in use case diagram

Tags: requirements, use-case

I have system requirements that the system will send an alert to the user.
This requirement is the most important requirement of my system.

Is it represented in the use case diagram or not?

Thank you.

Comment: If the information presented by the alert is relevant to the use case then yes.  I.e. "User attempts to submit username and password to the server.  An alert appears showing that password will expire within the next month and to change it.  User clicks on profile and then change password to change it."

Comment: We means by alert is that something happened. It's like Twitter notifications

Comment: Ok, well this is still applicable then.  If the alert results in the user taking action, then this is part of the use case.  Telling the user that there was a fatal program crash in an alert is an example of what *wouldn't* be included in a use case.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? It is your diagram, you can put anything into it what you like (as long as the notation allows it). And in this case, I can imagine an alert initiating a use case where a user will become involved.